# $~N~$ students come per $~0.5~$ hours( in $~30~$ minutes)in average and how many average in students come per hour?

Tags: probability, average, means

I've been doing the assignment of operations research .

The one copier (copy machine ) exists and we assume that student are making a queue to use the copier .

Students follow Poisson distribution and 5 students come in average per 30 minutes .

Then how many students come per hour?

I've thought that just simply multiplying it by 2 and have got 10 students per hour .

But I think it is wrong .

Can anyone give me what website should I refer?

Comment: This is what we call a Poisson process. You can read up on that. But for your case, multiplying by 2 correct. You can treat 1 hour as 2 independent blocks of 30 mins each.

Comment: I see . BTW , As the firstly given statement was 10 students come per hour in average , then 5 students come in average per 0.5 hours can't be generally held(said)?

Comment: You can. Recall what a Poisson process is. Given a rate parameter $\lambda$, and a time $t$, the expected number of observations is $\lambda t$. In your case, if we let $t = $ 1 hour, then half an hour is $t /2$. Therefore the expected number of observations over 0.5 hours is $\lambda t/2$.